# Getting IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python

I'm currently learning python from on Edx 'Python for the absolute beginner. i am to Create a program that inputs a phrase (like a famous quotation) and prints all of the words that start with h-z, i keep getting an error message on line, Here's the code,can someone please help out with a correction.

```
quote= input("enter a 1 sentence quote, non-alpha separate words:")
word=""
for char in quote:
    if char.isalpha() == True:
        word += char.upper()

    else:
        if word[0].lower() >= "h":
            print(word.upper())
            word=""

        else:
            word=""
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger to see what changes are being made to `word`?

Comment: At the first iteration `word` is an empty string and does not have `word[0]`.

Comment: Initially, there is no index 0 of `word`. So if the first character is not alpha, you get this error.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is entering on ELSE clause on the first loop. Since `word` is still empty, there is no `word[0]`.

But I really did not understand what you're exactly trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
quote=input("enter a 1 sentence quote, non-alpha separate words:")
[print(e) for e in quote.split(" ") if e[0].upper() in "HIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"]
```